# Will my profile be suspended if I upvote a (almost) daily active user?

Tags: discussion

Some members are more  active than others either by questioning, answering or both. Some of them are active daily (which thing is too beneficial for the community)

I noticed some members who always give interesting and convincing answers. Others ask frequently questions and you can learn from the question itself. For both types of members, I wonder if it is hard to resist to upvote each time (almost everyday) would lead to suspension of my profile for voting irregularities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all (or almost all) of your votes are for a single individual, then the first thing that would happen is that the votes would be cancelled. This is because this activity looks far too much like deliberately sock-puppeting or vote fraud.

Suspension is unlikely to happen unless you repeatedly do something against site rules. I'm not sure if that includes multiple instances of having your votes rolled back under the previous rule (and SE deliberately keep the specifics of these rules a secret so individuals do not try and game the system)

If in the course of normal voting, a particular individual gets a lot of upvotes, this probably isn't a problem, but make sure you also give time to others who may have good posts as well, and upvote them if they deserve it. Remember, votes are for posts (questions or answers) that you feel are good, or that help you, or are well written etc. Votes don't need to be saved for just the best posts - those ones will become evident as they earn many more votes.

Comment: As far as I know, getting a lot of upvotes is indeed "not a problem".

Comment: `and SE deliberately keep the specifics of these rules a secret so individuals do not try and game the system` Someone should mention Shannon's maxim to them. To be honest, that alone has given me a great temptation to attempt this only to learn these "secret rules". Not that I will, of course...

Comment: @forest a read of meta.se will give you enough insight. The rules themselves aren't secret so much, it's the thresholds...